# Joining views vs tables

Tags: sql, join, view

I'm getting different results when I pull data from a view vs the table directly, when I have a query with multiple joins. Is there a difference in how a view is joined vs a table?

For e.g. - field3 below is the exact same field, whether looked at via viewC or directly from tableC. yet the query yields different results.

```
select 
(sum(a.field1) + sum(b.field2) ) / sum(c.field3)
from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.id = b.id
left join tableC c on a.id = c.id
where datefield > 2017
and a.id > 1000
```

vs

```
select 
(sum(a.field1) + sum(b.field2) ) / sum(c.field3)
from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.id = b.id
left join viewC c on a.id = c.id
where datefield > 2017
and a.id > 1000
```

Comment: I'm guessing `viewC` does not contain all records from `tableC`....

Comment: There is no difference. It might be ordered differently. What do you mean by 'different results'? Is there the same number of records? What kind of SQL is this? Oracle? SQL Server?